# (being ADMIN of a website) how to get id and password via email. instead of trying to decrypt md5

Tags: php, wordpress, admin

I've created a website now I want to get id and password of those people who are getting registered. after reg.. the website sends activation link to user. and i want to send them id and password along with activation link their email id. And a copy of that email to my email id......

I tried to edit in pluggable.php but it is not working. 
$blogname = wp_specialchars_decode(get_option('blogname'), ENT_QUOTES);

```
$message  = sprintf(__('New user registration on your site %s:'), $blogname) . "\r\n\r\n";
$message .= sprintf(__('Username: %s'), $user->user_login) . "\r\n\r\n";
$message .= sprintf(__('E-mail: %s'), $user->user_email) . "\r\n";

@wp_mail(get_option('admin_email'), sprintf(__('[%s] New User Registration'), $blogname), $message);

if ( empty($plaintext_pass) )
    return;

$message  = sprintf(__('Username: %s'), $user->user_login) . "\r\n";
$message .= sprintf(__('Password: %s'), $plaintext_pass) . "\r\n";
$message .= wp_login_url() . "\r\n";

wp_mail($user->user_email, sprintf(__('[%s] Your username and password'), $blogname), $message);
```

Comment: I will probably never want to sign up for a website that sends a copy of any email to the owner.

Comment: This sounds incredibly insecure.

Comment: _instead of trying to decrypt md5_... that isn't even a valid option. "Decrypting" md5 may not necessarily yield the original password.

Comment: First off, it's not legal to do what you want to in some countries. Not only can you get sued, you are compromising the overall security of people using that website. Second, MD5 cannot be decrypted. It's not an encryption algorithm. It's a hashing algorithm.

Comment: If you are the admin, why do you want to receive a copy of registration emails, if you want to now when a new user has joined your site, send a notification email to yourself, you don't need to worry about username/password because you have access to the database

Comment: this sounds like a horrible idea on so many levels.

Comment: i've not done this. I just wanna know is this possible if yes how? just for curisity.....